# Character Loss converting _GET Array to URL string

Tags: php

Having a very bizarre issue with the conversion of a $_GET request into a string.
**(PHP 5.2.17)**

Here is a small snippet of the problem area of the array from print_r():

```
_GET (array)
  ...
  [address_country_code] => GB
  [address_name] => Super Mario
  [notify_version] => 3.7
  ...
```

There are two cases the _GET data is used:

**Case 1):** Saved then used later:

```
// Script1.php

$data = json_encode($_GET);
# > Save to MySQL Database ($data)


// Script2.php (For Viewing & Testing URL later)

# > Load from Database ($result)
echo http_build_query(json_decoded($result,true));
```

**Result of above array snippet:** (CORRECT OUTPUT)

> address_country_code=GB&address_name=Super+Mario&notify_version=3.7

**Case 2):** Used in same script as Case 1) just before its saved in Case 1):

```
// Script1.php

echo http_build_query($_GET);
```

**Results in:** (INCORRECT OUTPUT)

> address_country_code=GB&address_name=Super+Mario¬ify_version=3.7

How is it possible that a few chars are output as a ¬ in case 2 yet case 1 is fine!
It is driving me insane :(

I have tried also instead of using http_build_query a custom function that generates the url using urlencode() in the Key and Value of the foreach loop, this just resulted in the the ¬ being changed to %C2%AC in one of my test cases!

Comment: Just going to hazard a guess here, but since ¬ is a logical negation symbol (effectively "not") with the HTML entity code of **&not;** - I'd check to see if you're using something like `html_entity_decode()` on that URL, since you've got `&not`ify_version=...

Comment: @CD001 Both cases display in a web browser, both a directly output from http_build_query yet only one is effected by &not;
But I have have solved the issue buy going back to the custom function for the one causing the issue. Using urlencode on the vars and keys and imploding with &amp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, even though both cases output to web a web browser and both convert from an array using http_build_query().

I fixed problem in Case 2 by replacing http_build_query (Case 1 still uses it..) with this function:

```
htmlspecialchars(http_build_query($_GET));
```

Comment: I figured out why! :/
http_build_query() works fine when you are printing out into a Hyperlink! <a href="<?=$url.http_build_query($vars);?>"</a>

No good though for direct output into text body
Have to use above function...

Comment: your function is redundant `htmlspecialchars(http_build_query($_GET))`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok with your data. You can verify it if you do:

```
$query = http_build_query($_GET);
parse_str($query, $data);
print_r($data);
```

you will get the correct uncorrupted data.

And the reason why you see `¬` symbol is how browser interprets html entities. ¬ is represented as `&not;` But browser will render it even without semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely displaying this data in a web browser and that is interpreting

```
&not
```

as special HTML entity.

Pls see this: https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/NotCharacterEntity

Try doing

```
var_dump(http_build_query($_GET))
```

instead of:

```
echo http_build_query($_GET)
```

and see HTML source to get/verify actual string.